# MathContexts in BigDecimals - ScalaCheck generator creates BigDecimals which can't be serialized then deserialized. How to use MathContexts correctly?

Tags: scala, precision, bigdecimal, scalacheck, mathcontext

I discovered [an issue in Scalacheck](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/124) whereby `arbitrary[BigDecimal]` would generate `BigDecimal`s which could not be converted to `String`s and then back into `BigDecimal`s, and I'm trying to work with the creator to find a fix for it, but I'm unsure of how the `MathContext`s come into play.

The [original generator](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/f1e0206d7d2fa5a5b8d2137c0f6c5c462ebd1eab/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Arbitrary.scala#L185-L202) looks like this:

```
/** Arbitrary BigDecimal */
implicit lazy val arbBigDecimal: Arbitrary[BigDecimal] = {
  import java.math.MathContext._
  val mcGen = oneOf(UNLIMITED, DECIMAL32, DECIMAL64, DECIMAL128)
  val bdGen = for {
    x <- arbBigInt.arbitrary
    mc <- mcGen
    limit <- const(if(mc == UNLIMITED) 0 else math.max(x.abs.toString.length - mc.getPrecision, 0))
    scale <- Gen.chooseNum(Int.MinValue + limit , Int.MaxValue)
  } yield {
    try {
      BigDecimal(x, scale, mc)
    } catch {
      case ae: java.lang.ArithmeticException => BigDecimal(x, scale, UNLIMITED) // Handle the case where scale/precision conflict
    }
  }
  Arbitrary(bdGen)
}
```

The problem lies within the fact that the [`BigDecimal` constructor used](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.math.BigInteger,%20int,%20java.math.MathContext%29) inverts the sign of the `scale` argument, thereby making `Int.MinValue` turn into a `scale` bigger than 2^32 -1.

```
scala> val orig = BigDecimal(BigInt("-28334198897217871282176"), -2147483640, UNLIMITED)
orig: scala.math.BigDecimal = -2.8334198897217871282176E+2147483662

scala> BigDecimal(orig.toString)
java.lang.NumberFormatException
  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:554)
  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:383)
  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:806)
  at scala.math.BigDecimal$.exact(BigDecimal.scala:125)
  at scala.math.BigDecimal$.apply(BigDecimal.scala:283)
  ... 33 elided
```

The core of the fix is to increase the lower bound by the number of digits in the `unscaledVal`, but I only thought of a way to do it with only `MathContext.UNLIMITED`. I fear we miss out on generator robustness if we do that:

```
lazy val genBigDecimal: Gen[BigDecimal] = for {
  unscaledVal <- arbitrary[BigInt]
  scale <- Gen.chooseNum(Int.MinValue + unscaledVal.abs.toString.length, Int.MaxValue)
} yield BigDecimal(unscaledVal, scale)
```

**So, if we want to keep using the other `MathContext`s, what do we have to do to ensure we use them correctly?**

Comment: If you believe this to be a bug in the Scala library, you should file it at issues.scala-lang.org and have the discussion about fixes there.

Comment: @RexKerr It's not a Scala bug. You can reproduce this in Java: http://ideone.com/ZNOQ1Q

Comment: Sure, but it could be interpreted as a bug that Scala doesn't work around it.  If we're happy to say it's Java's fault and leave it at that, then don't file a bug report (or maybe if you do it will be closed as "wontfix; reason--Java should fix it on their end").